# Is it necessary to abandon too large variable on stack to avoid stack copying in go1.4?

Tags: go

As we know, goroutine's stack could increase by copying the stack in go1.4. My question is, Is it necessary to avoid too large local variable on stack in go?
for example

```
func foo(){
   var buf [8096]int
   //do something with buf
}
```

or

```
var buf [8096]int
func foo(){      
   //do something with buf
}
```

I mean, is it necessary to use the latter example to avoid large variable because of stack copying?

Comment: Can you post a real example that shows bad performance because of stack splitting? Answering the question in the abstract isn't possible because to get efficient code you need to profile.

Comment: Just because something is in a function body doesn't mean it's on the stack. AFAIK, Go's compiler sometimes arbitrarily allocates very large locals on the heap even if they don't escape for performance reasons.

Comment: http://golang.org/doc/faq#stack_or_heap

Answer (score 2):

Stack is almost always faster then heap. Where to define variable is more about scope. Since Go is lexically scoped language in latter example you dirty up global namespace, making var buf visible anywhere in your program. It's semantic difference. So you should better do things semanticaly correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reallocate another big object in the stack you should use pointer instead of global variables. As for go1.4 this code works:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func do(v *[3]int) {
    v[1] = 99
}

func main() {
    var r [3]int
    do(&r)
    fmt.Println(r)
    //Prints [0 99 0]
}
```

If you don't use pointers this will fail because arrays are passed as value, not reference:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func do(v [3]int) {
    v[1] = 99
}

func main() {
    var r [3]int
    do(r)
    fmt.Println(r)
    //Prints [0 0 0]
}
```

**Note: this does not apply to slices; slices are always passed as reference.**